# How to calculate amount of energy transferred

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I am trying to add heat-metering functionality to existing flow meter.

I added two RTD sensors for measuring temperature of at flow side and return side.

Basically, below picture explains the configuration.

[image]

Given that I have flowing number,

$Q$ = Flow Rate ($\mathrm{m^3/s}$)

$T_1$ = Temperature at flow side (Kelvin)

$T_2$ = Temperature at return side (Kelvin)

How can I determine heat transfer rate in $\mathrm{kW}$ from above numbers?

Do I need another parameter depending on the type of fluid flowing inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume incompressible flow. If $\rho$ is fluid density, $C_p$ its specific heat at constant pressure, then heat transfer rate is $\rho Q C_p (T_1-T_2)$.